# Separate view model class vs properties with functions

Tags: c#, oop

I'm wondering if I should have a class for just my view model or if I should keep my properties and methods in a single class.  Is there a best practice for this?

Here is the example that shows having a separate view model class:

```
public class vmCustomer
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Customer
{
     public vmCustomer GetCustomer(decimal id)
     {
           ...
           return customer;
     }
}
```

Here is the example that shows having my properties and methods in a single class:

```
public class Customer
{
     public string FullName { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }

     public Customer GetCustomer(decimal id)
     {
           ...
           return customer;
     }
}
```

In OOP development is there one better preferred?  Would the SOLID principles say a separate view model because of the single responsibility rule?

Comment: What does `GetCustomer` do, does it read from a database? (Anyhow I guess it should be `static`)

Comment: If GetCustomer load a customer from somwhere, (db, file, webservice, whatever), I would not insert the method in Customer class. Leave the "responsability" to load customer to a different class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewModel is a "bridge" between view and model. The real data should be in model, in viewmodel data should be in format, which enables binding to the view.

Also selecting customer by id should be in service class, called by viewmodel.

```
public class VmCustomerDetail
{
    private ICustomerService customerService;
    public Customer CustomerDetail {get; set;}

    public async void Refresh(int id){
        CustomerDetail = customerService.GetById(id);
    }
}

public class Customer
{
     public string FullName { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }    
}

public interface ICustomerService{
    Customer GetById(int id);
}

public class CustomerService : ICustomerService{
    Customer GetById(int id){
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I put the GetById, UpdateCustomer, InsertCustomer all in a single service class?  If not, how should I manage this?

Comment: All the data you want to put into your ViewModel should be loaded through service classes... For internal functionality at "deeper" level, this is not neccessary.

Comment: Could you have done this without interfaces?  What is the advantage of using the interface?  Thanks libik!

Comment: @JHunt - For desing time data. You can write DesignCustomerService and CustomerService classes which implements that interface. Then you can configure that in desing time mode, the DesignCustomerService is selected. With this, you can see real data behaviour in your designer even without running the program.

Usually you do not "select it" from database or server in Design services, you just create some data manually. But it is enough for easy positioning etc.